# Please help with installing PostgreSQL in a Django project on Linux Mint "Uma"

Tags: postgresql, installation

I installed postgres like this:,

- `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib`
- `sudo systemctl is-active postgresql`, returned active
- `sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql`, returned enabled
- `sudo systemctl status postgresql`, returned active

but when I try confirming if the Postgresql server is ready to accept connections from clients as follows:

- `sudo pg_isready`, this returned `/var/run/postgresql:5432 - no response`.

I've tried all with no success please help, thanks in advance.

OS: Linux Mint "Uma"

Answer (score 0):

I edited  `postgresql.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
```

Enable or add:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Restart the database engine:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Also, you can check the file `pg_hba.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
```

And add your network or host address:

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24
```